# Exit code in powershell still zero even though cmdlet throws an error

Tags: powershell

Suppose I `cd` to an empty directory in powershell and run the following command:

`get-childitem x`

The command will throw an error that it cannot find the path, which is expected.

However, when I check the `$LastExitCode` it is still zero.

This is confusing to me, since according to the docs `$LastExitCode` should contain the exit code of the last windows-based program that was run.

Could anyone please explain why the exit code is still zero after I run a command which clearly fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get-childitem` doesn't start a new process. If a powershell function or command throws an error it will be stored in the global `$Error` array. `$LASTEXITCODE` is created and set when you start a child process, for example a new powershell session with a command:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem x
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\x' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem x
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\x:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\> $Error.Count
1
PS C:\> $Error[0]
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\x' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem x
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\x:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\> $LASTEXITCODE
PS C:\> powershell -Command { get-childitem x }
get-childitem : Cannot find path 'C:\x' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+  get-childitem x
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\x:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\> $LASTEXITCODE
1
PS C:\> powershell -Command { get-childitem . }


    Directory: C:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
.....
.....
.....


PS C:\> $LASTEXITCODE
0
PS C:\>
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification on the difference between starting a child process and running from the current process.

Comment: I would add that there is also `$?` which could be used if you just want to check if the last command or process was successful (in case of process this means `$LASTEXITCODE` is not 0). Note that for processes one could not rely on `$?` until recently (PS 7.1.x or 7.2.x, I'm not sure).

Comment: I've checked, `$?` has been fixed for native processes with PS 7.1 (see [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-71?view=powershell-7.2#breaking-changes-and-improvements))

Answer (score -1):

In a powershell script you can do something like this at the bottom:

```
exit $error.count
```

Then the exit code will be the number of errors.